# Handle screen rotation progress without losing data by using Seekbar - Android Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, kotlin, android-seekbar

I am newbie on android studio, i had face problem on when i rotation the screen the seek bar progress will be reset it to 0, that i had try using saved Instance State but the progress still reset it , can anyone help me give me some solution to solve it ?

I get this error **Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but Int was expected**

Thank you all .Hope will get back soon ya

above is the code at MainActivity.kt

```
//the bottom one
var no:Int=0
private val SEEKBAR ="seekbar"

//Inside the onCreate
    if (savedInstanceState !=null)       {
        val value = savedInstanceState.getString(SEEKBAR)
        seekbar1.progress=value
        no= value?.toInt() ?:0
    }

//after the onCreate
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

val seekbar1 = seekbar1.progress.toString()
outState.putString(SEEKBAR,seekbar1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing string to the progress function of seekbar.
We need to pass integer.
So, simply use
`seekbar_weight.progress = value.toInt()`

**UPDATE AFTER GOING THROUGH YOUR CODE:**

In your code, in the `setVariable()` function, you are setting some UI's according to the Units user picked.

While doing that, you are setting your progress of the seekbar to 0. And this function is being called after the progress value is restored from `onRestoreInstateState`. After it gets restored, you are again setting it back to zero from `setVariable()` function.

So, you just need to remove 8 lines (which are used to set seekbar progress and text to show seekbar progress) from your `setVariable()` function.

So, your `setVariable()` function should look like:

```
    private fun setVariable() {
    //Set the text of units and the max progress
    spinner_units.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(
            parent: AdapterView<*>?,
            view: View?,
            position: Int,
            id: Long
        ) {
            if (position == 0) {
                text_weight.text = "Weight (kg)"
                text_height.text = "Height (cm)"
                seekbar_weight.max = 450
                seekbar_height.max = 250
                number_picker_age.value = 2
                bmi_meter.speedTo(0F)
            } else if (position == 1) {
                text_weight.text = "Weight (ibs)"
                text_height.text = "Height (in)"
                seekbar_weight.max = 770
                seekbar_height.max = 80
                number_picker_age.value = 2
                bmi_meter.speedTo(0F)
            }

        }
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2: AFTER UPDATED REQUIREMENT**

For your updated requirement here you can go:
Bring back those 8 lines those were deleted from `setVariable()` method.

In your `strings.xml` file, add one item 'Select' in the string array for the spinner.

```
<string-array name="units">
        <item>Select</item>
        <item>Metric</item>
        <item>Imperial</item>
</string-array>
```

In `MainActivity`, override `onPause()` method and set the spinner to position 0.

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    spinner_units.setSelection(0)
}
```

That should solve your problem. If not please comment back.

Comment: Hi, that i had try to add in but is cannot be work , when i rotate also same the value will be reset , still got other solution ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You just need to replace your setVariable() function with my code. Your problem will be fixed.

Comment: Hi Skafle, that I had remove it the code 8 line , it's work when rotation it will be not reset. But right now I got other problem that is when i select different unit the progress will not be reset. That are other way that can be solve it the problem on rotation and also select different unit will be reset the seekbar ? I also thank alot ya

Comment: I have updated my answer for second time. Please check it out and see if it works.

Comment: Thank ya , I would try it later

Comment: I figure out that the Seek bar will be auto store when you rotation the screen , anyway i also thank ya

Answer (score 0):

How about trying `onRestoreInstanceState` which is triggered only when something was saved in `onSaveInstanceState` method and returns non-null.

However you need to use `putInt()` instead of `putString()` since the value of SeekBar is an `Integer`

```
 override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        val seekbar1 = seekBar1.progress

        //use putInt() method 
        outState.putInt(SEEKBAR, seekbar1)
    }


    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

        //retrieve value using getInt() method
        val value = savedInstanceState.getInt(SEEKBAR)
        seekBar1.progress = value

    }
```

Let us know how it goes.

Cheers.

Comment: so when i using onRestoreIntanceState that inside my if and else how to call to use it , i had no idea on this ... can give me some guideline or idea ?

Comment: Hi Yong Wei, you can use either `onCreate()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()`. The good thing with onRestoreInstanceState() is that is only called when an instance is saved and _will never return a nullable savedInstanceState_ so no need for `-if-else` . If you choose to use `onCreate()` then you need to use `if-else`. Please try and let me know.

Comment: Hi Tonnie, i cannot get you , i still very newbie in android studio , sorry about that, so that right now for this solution is that i need to using onRestoreInstanceState then no need to use onSaveInstanceState ? or both also i need to use it. and how to declare the function i just put below the onCreate but i had try it , but when rotate also will be reset

Comment: Please refer to my code above, You will still need to override both  `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onCreate()' like I have done. For restoring the value you can either do it inside `onCreate()` (like you had done before ) or choose to add `onRestoreInstanceState()' method and move the restore code inside `onRestoreInstance()'.

Comment: Hi Tonnie,i had added this link [Image](https://ibb.co/Q61tTHF) that already added your code inside my project also cannot be work , when i rotate also will be reset , still got other solution to fix it ? Thank ya

Comment: Hello Yong, have seen the image and to see where the issue is I will need to debug your code from my laptop. For  this you will need to [put your code on GitHub](https://medium.com/code-yoga/how-to-link-android-studio-with-github-312037a13b99) . You can [create an GitHub account](https://github.com/)and then upload your project so that I can see it.

Comment: Hi,i add push to the code to [Github](https://github.com/fackerlee/BMI-Calculator) see you can be access or not, really thank your for extra debug my code...

Comment: Good work, let me look at the issue and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Have gone through your code and did a Debug as promised.

**Problem**

Your activity is being recreated every time you rotate the phone.

This is triggering the `onCreate()` each time which makes this line of code to be invoked.

`setReferences()//Setup Gui Components`

`setReferences()` is the one making everything to be reset and **go back to zero**.

**Solution**

Go to your manifest file and add this line of code.

`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden">`

Have provided you with the image below ...

[image]

This will stop your activity from recreated every time there is a rotation and `setReferences()` will only be called once.

Next delete these two functions `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` as you no longer need them.

Comment: Isn't that an inferior solution?

Comment: The way you proposed can stop recreation of activity but that is not recommended and should only be used as a last resort.
[Documentation Link] (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#HandlingTheChange)
You have mentioned 4 configuration changes, but there are several other configuration changes which will lead to recreation of activity.


I also went through the code and found the cause of error and suggested the solution.

Comment: Hi Tonnie ,thank for helping debug the code, but i can saying this are not much help for me , it is because that i had different layout for landscape if that i using `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden">` that when i rotate the layout will be totally same with my portrait. At your previously code that using `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` will be helpfully and that @skafle had debug that code and remove the 8 line from the set variable. Do you had any solution that when I select different unit the progress will be reset to 0 ?